# Can someone die before her fixed time due to medical fault

Tags: death, belief

For example say, someone is taking care of a patient and he mistakenly gave wrong treatment to his patient. If that patient dies for that reason, can we say that the patient died before her fate death came due to the mistake of the patient's attendant?

Comment: Try to use more clear words, and also try adding what you have researched. This question is too vague.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The question answers itself.

If her death is **fixed** due to medical fault then she would pass away due to that reason. That she would die due to medical fault is blotted for her.

Otherwise the word **fixed** would not bear any meaning. So, no one can die **before** or **after**.

This is a part of belief for the Muslims. A believer must believe in it that whatever that comes at his way is blotted for him; which we call **fate**.

> وَأَنَّهُ هُوَ أَمَاتَ وَأَحْيَا
>
> That it is He Who granteth Death and Life; [[53:44]](https://quran.com/53/44)

Answer (score 0):

No. At first, how do you know that the time for death was some another time in the future? Nobody can know when anybody will die, nor their future, nor their fate. We can say only the time of death, after death has occured. By definition, the time of death is when somebody died, which we can only know after death. We don't know fate, thus we can't argue that the real time of death is different from the time of death in the fate.